# How to get textfield characters?(Xcode)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm beginning to learn Xcode and as the first app i decided to write a calculator. I did everything and it works pretty good but there is one thing i couldn't find. I want when the user writes Letters instead of numbers and taps the button , an alert appear and prevents him from entering letters.I'll appreciate you if help me and sry for my bad english.

Comment: Why don't you just eliminate the possibility of the user typing numbers? Also, may want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719680/iphone-uitextfield-only-integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment said, you'll probably be better off just changing the input type of the keyboard.

```
[myTextField setKeyBoardType:UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad] // has a decimal, use UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad for no decimal
```

See list of all available types [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html).

Comment: Sorry guys i'm new and i don't know hot to vote your comments. Anyway thank u so much for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to allow the user to type letters *at all* you'll be much better off using the *numeric keyboard*. The decimal numeric keypad is available in iOS 4.1 and up, and you can find out more about it from this question:

[How to use the new UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad feature in iOS 4.1 SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742642/how-to-use-the-new-uikeyboardtypedecimalpad-feature-in-ios-4-1-sdk)